# Efficient way of getting Convex hull of Zonotopes

Tags: convex-geometry, polytopes

Given a set of vectors/generators $V \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, one can obtain a Zonotope via Minkowski Sum $Z = \bigoplus_{i \in V} i$.

Given a set of set of vectors $G = \{V_1, V_2, \cdots, V_n \}$, one can generate $S = \cup_{i=1}^n Z_i$. And my questions is how to get vertices of $CH(S)$,given $G$ ? Here $CH$ is the convex hull.

Comment: Find the vertices of each zonotope in linear time and then find the convex hull of all the vertices in time $O(n \log n)$

Comment: right, this is the straightforward approach, but I'm wondering if one can get any faster, as $n$ is relatively big in my context.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4235950/convex-hull-of-combinatorial-zonotopes this post covers more on how to generate $n$

Comment: You can find the convex hull of two convex polygons in linear time but I don't know any fast way to do that for $n$ polygons