# Convex hull of combinatorial Zonotopes

Tags: combinatorics, polygons, convex-geometry

Given a set of vectors/generators $V \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, one can obtain a Zonotope via Minkowski Sum $Z = \bigoplus_{i \in V} i$.

On the other hand, Given a set of sets of generators $C = \{ V_1, V_2, \cdots, V_n\}$, one can construct a Zonotope combinatorially. Namely, $Z_k = \bigoplus_{j \in V_i} j , \forall i \in [1, \cdots, n]$, for every set of generators $V_i$, i can choose any element $j$ and in total $n$ vectors was added to form a Zonotope $Z_k$.

Now my question is how to obtain the vertices of convex hull of union of all possible $Z_k$ given $C$ ?